# How to avoid an anchoring error when re-parenting a QML object

Tags: qml

In a QML Item, I want a graphical effect to be shown, and, during its animation, I want a part of the GUI to be disabled. The Item must not know how it is used precisely.
I acheived this behaviour by adding my component a target property to « freeze » and filling this target component with a `MouseArea` that catches events.
I'm totally satisfied with the behaviour so far, except for a small error that appears during runtime :

```
QML MouseArea: Cannot anchor to an item that isn't a parent or sibling.
```

Here is the code of the MouseArea (grid is an id I use for testing) :

```
Item
{
    id: starterCircle
    property var freeze: grid

    MouseArea
    {
        id: inhibit
        parent: starterCircle.freeze.parent 
        anchors.fill: starterCircle.freeze // generates an error before re-parenting
    }
}
```

If I change the `MouseArea` to this, I won't be annoyed by the error, but it looks like a dirty hack to me :

```
    MouseArea
    {
        id: inhibit
        parent: starterCircle.freeze.parent 
        onParentChanged: if (starterCircle.freeze.parent === parent) anchors.fill = starterCircle.freeze
    }
```

I should mention a strange behaviour : if I log the parent property of the `MouseArea` when its `parent` is changed, I get the same parent twice printed in the log, and there is no more error. That is, the following code gives no error :

```
    MouseArea
    {
        id: inhibit
        parent: starterCircle.freeze.parent 
        anchors.fill: starterCircle.freeze
        onParentChanged: console.log(parent)
    }
```

Note that I can live with an error, or a hack to prevent it from being generated. But I probably missed something in order to get things right. I'm using Qt 5.9.2.

Comment: `[...] I get the same parent twice printed in the log[...]` can you double-check that? I get a series as such: `orignal parent => null => new parent`, which is, as I first parent to the object it is created in, then I parent to null (as `property var freeze` is undefined initially, before the binding is evaluated and `grid` is assigned, and then it is re-parented to my `grid.parent`-Item, once that is created. I still use 5.9.1 however.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest is to use a conditional binding:

```
anchors.fill: (starterCircle.freeze.parent === parent 
               ? starterCircle.freeze
               : null)
```

Comment: It may be more concise, but still is the same hack to me.

Comment: It is not just more concise but also a good way to prevent warnings when you can't make sure that properties you bind to, are ready when you want to create the binding. It is like the nullptr-check in C++.